# Difference in differences for multiple data with different intervention times?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons, difference-in-difference

I am trying to examine the effects of COVID-19 related lockdowns and was told by a friend that D-in-D would be a good way to handle this.  I have looked at some tutorials/youtube videos but everything I have found only deals with 1 control and 1 variable group. Is it possible to extend the analysis with multiple control and variable groups?

My data right now is in the form:

```
time    city1    city1_lockdown   city2    city2_lockdown ...... city10   city10_lockdown
1/1/20    5          0             12           0                 x             x
2/1/20    7          0             10           0                 x             x
3/1/20    8          0             11           1                 x             x 
....                         ........                    ........
10/10/20  14         0             12           1                 x             x
11/10/20  13         0             20           0                 x             x
```

where some cities never experienced lockdown (eg. city1, city 5, etc) and the others did experience lockdown but at different times (e.g. city2 from march-may, city4 from april-july, etc). Not all data exists for the entire time (e.g. city10 only has data for, say, feb-aug but I would like to include it)

I guess my questions are:

1. is D-in-D the right approach?
2. is this an appropriate format to continue in for D-in-D analysis or do I need to refactor?
3. the prebuilt options in python seem lacking,  am i missing something or should i switch to R? (I don't have access to stata unfortunately)

Thank you for any guidance!

edit: A much more basic question since maybe I don't understand DID as well as I thought...

How would the actual formula I construct look? Is it like:

(control) ~ (offset) + lockdown + lockdown*(variable city) ?

Comment: You have only one treatment (lockdown) with variable timing, so no need for multiple groups. Do a search for “generalized DID” here to find many examples.

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov Ok so maybe I should add another question because this is unclear to me...if I use a generalized DID approach then I just get 1 coefficient out, right? All the controls effectively collapse into 1 group and all the variables do the same into another group, right? If I had reason to believe that each lockdown was implemented differently and therefore might have different impacts, I would have to do the analysis for each individual city vs the effective group of controls?

Comment: Do you observe what is different about each lockdown (other than timing)? How many lockdown types are there?

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov other than timing no. There's probably like 100+ different types since there are a lot of factors that go into a given city/country's lockdown and each place implemented different factors at different times: is there a curfew (and when to when)? is public transportation allowed? are private cars allowed? are planes flying? are schools in session? are gatherings of people limited and to how many people? etc.etc.etc.

Comment: It sounds like you have an unknown number of latent lockdown types since you don’t have their characteristics (though they are probably observable). If you were willing to take a stand on the number and that number is small, a finite mixture model with a DiD spec might work. You could also pursue a synthetic cohort approach, which would give you unit-specific effects as well as the average effect. Of course you will need to worry about spillovers of all kinds between geos, and also about whether lockdowns happen because transient local shocks that also alter your outcome.

Comment: Also, why did you put your cross-sectional units (i.e., cities) across each column? Did you do this for demonstration purposes? Is `city1` your outcome and `city1_lockdown` the treatment dummy for your first city? Just curious. I also wonder if you could categorize cities by the *intensity* of their lockdowns, but that would require you to observe their characteristics, as previously noted.

Comment: @ThomasBilach i'm actually looking at pollution impacts from lockdowns so city(x) is, e.g., the pm2.5 measurement from that city, for that day. cityx_lockdown is my dummy for if there is a lockdown during that day. I realize that with DID i'm making the assumption that the overall trends outside of lockdowns are the same but I think it's ok in my case.

Comment: What is your offset here? Is your outcome the mean concentration of particulate matter in a spatial unit? Will you be treating particulate matter concentration as a continuous variable? Your offset suggests you're using a Poisson model.